# How to validate a input text filed only allow letters not allow Number and symbol?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to make my Wordpress contact form 7 input text field only taken letters not allow symbol and ay special charters it it possibile please help me.
this is i am using code for this

if ( 1 !== preg_match ( "#^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}$#",$a, $your_fullname) )

Answer (score 0):

This will check if `$a` contains only letters (uppercase or lowercase) or whitespace:

```
if (preg_match('#^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}$#', $a) == 1) {
    echo "ok\n";
}
```